# scikit SVM returns ValueError: X.shape[1] = 181 should be equal to 865, the number of features at training time?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I am training SVM on a combination of string and numeric dataset, below is the code and my test and training set. When I am running the code, it throws following error.

```
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
 import scipy.sparse as sp
 import sklearn.preprocessing
 import sklearn.decomposition
 import sklearn.linear_model
 import sklearn.pipeline
 import sklearn.metrics
 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
 from sklearn import svm


 class UniRank(object):
     vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 3))

    def __init__(self, trained_data_csv, sep=","):
        df = pd.read_csv(trained_data_csv, sep=sep)
        sample = df[['Name', 'Location']]
        sample = sample.apply(lambda col: col.str.strip())
        # convert the characters to matrix
        train = sp.hstack(sample.apply(lambda col: self.vect.fit_transform(col)))
        values = df[['score']]
        values.to_records()
        # feature selection and manipulation
        self.clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100)
        X,y = train, values
        # applying the model
        self.clf.fit(X,y)

    def test(self, test_data_csv, sep=","):
        df = pd.read_csv(test_data_csv, sep=sep)
        sample = df[['Name', 'Location']]
        sample = sample.apply(lambda col: col.str.strip())
        test = sp.hstack(sample.apply(lambda col:   self.vect.fit_transform(col)))
    return self.clf.predict(test)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ur = UniRank('/home/maitreyee/Documents/Rdata/classifyUniWithR/version2/scored_collg1.csv')
    print ur.test('/home/maitreyee/Documents/Rdata/classifyUniWithR/version2/test1uni.csv')
```

and following is the error when I run the above script

```
/home/maitreyee/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn    /svm/base.py:472: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a     1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ),     for example using ravel().
  y_ = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uni_rank2.py", line 40, in <module>
    print ur.test('/home/maitreyee/Documents/Rdata/classifyUniWithR/version2/test1uni.csv')
  File "uni_rank2.py", line 35, in test
     return self.clf.predict(test)
   File "/home/maitreyee/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn   /svm/base.py", line 500, in predict
     y = super(BaseSVC, self).predict(X)
  File "/home/maitreyee/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 290, in predict
    X = self._validate_for_predict(X)
  File "/home/maitreyee/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 443, in _validate_for_predict
    (n_features, self.shape_fit_[1]))
ValueError: X.shape[1] = 181 should be equal to 865, the number of   features at training time
```

my training set

```
Index,Name,Location,loc_val,sal_val,mean_rank,mean_score,sum_score,score
0,Indian Institute of Technology (IITDelhi),Delhi,0.0128,1.028125,0.0162,0.352375,1.057125,100
1,Indian Institute of Technology (IITDelhi),Delhi,0.0128,0.990625,0.0162,0.339875,1.019625,100
2,Indian Institute of Technology (IITDelhi),Delhi,0.0128,0.959375,0.0162,0.3294583333,0.988375,100
3,Indian Institute of Technology (IITBombay),Bombay,0.008,1,0.02025,0.34275,1.02825,100
4,Indian Institute of Technology (IITBombay),Bombay,0.008,1,0.02025,0.34275,1.02825,100
5,Indian Institute of Technology (IITBombay),Bombay,0.008,1,0.02025,0.34275,1.02825,100
6,Indian Institute of Technology (IITKharagpur),Kharagpur,0.0176,0.991875,0.022275,0.3439166667,1.03175,100
7,Indian Institute of Technology (IITKharagpur),Kharagpur,0.0176,1.0125,0.022275,0.3507916667,1.052375,100
8,Indian Institute of Technology (IITKharagpur),Kharagpur,0.0176,0.95375,0.022275,0.3312083333,0.993625,100
9,Indian Institute of Technology (IITMadras),Madras,0.0224,0.9875,0.02835,0.3460833333,1.03825,100
```

Test set

```
Index,Name,Location,location_val,salary_val,mean_rank,mean_score,sum_score
254,Gandhi Institute of Technology and Management Engineering,Vishakapatnam,0.0096,0.4925,0.5508,0.3509666667,1.0529
255,Cochin University of science and technology Engineering,Cochin,0.0112,0.296875,0.62775,0.3119416667,0.935825
256,Cochin University of science and technology Engineering,Cochin,0.0112,0.443125,0.62775,0.3606916667,1.082075
257,Cochin University of science and technology Engineering,Cochin,0.0112,0.296875,0.62775,0.3119416667,0.935825
258,KC College of Arts Science & Commerce Arts,Lucknow,0.008,0.21875,0.32805,0.1849333333,0.5548
259,Faculty of Arts University of Lucknow Arts,Lucknow,0.0032,0.21875,0.3483,0.1900833333,0.57025
260,Scottish Church College Arts,Kolkata,0.0192,0.21875,0.3564,0.1981166667,0.59435
261,L.D. Arts College Arts,Ahmedabad,0.0112,0,0.3645,0.1252333333,0.3757
262,St. Francis College for Women Arts,Hyderabad,0.0112,0.125,0.2997,0.1453,0.4359
263,Wilson College Arts,Mumbai,0.008,0.125,0.3807,0.1712333333,0.5137
264,PSG College of Arts & Science Arts,Coimbatore,0.0064,0.125,0.3888,0.1734,0.5202
```

I am using SVM for string data for the first time in python. If there are any better ways to train SVM on string set kindly let me know.